# Regular Expression Quantifier (Without Repetition)

Tags: regex

I'm trying to use regular expressions to find combinations of characters in sequence. The following are all valid options:

```
ABCD
AD
ACD
BDC
BD
B
CD
CDE
EDA
EDB
E
```

These characters will be smattered throughout a larger string, either in sequence or otherwise for example

```
"Here is a string that will ABCD have some in it" -- ABCD (1 occurrence)
"Another string with EDAEDBCD some in it" -- EDA, EDB, CD (3 occurrences)
"Here ACD is a E string with ACD a bunch AD" -- ACD, E, ACD, AD (4 occurrences)
"And another ABCDE" -- ABCD, E (2 occurrences)
```

Using the following RegEx I can find each character combination pulling the longest option for each of those with characters contained in another:

```
(A(?:[C|B|D](?:[C|D](?:[D])?)?))|
(C(?:[D](?:[E])?))|
(B(?:[D](?:[C])?)?)|
(E(?:[D](?:[A|B]))?)
```

I want to--with one regular expression--find if the string has three or more instances from this list only using the longest possible version of each sequence (i.e. BDC counts as one despite BD and B both being valid options). I've tried using the {3,} quantifier, but it double counts the sets.

Unfortunately the system will only take a true/false result of a regular expression and I can't do anything more with it. I do understand this may be impossible.

Comment: What flavor of regex are you using? Different programming languages support different features.

Comment: @4castle It seems to be either Perl or C++, I unfortunately have to enter this into a dashboard and it's applied behind the scenes and our reps know nothing about the actual mechanics that support the dashboard

Comment: @Jan unfortunately no, that expression would include any combination of A-E with 3 characters or more rather than recognizing each of the given possibilities as a distinct result, it also includes some combinations I am not looking for

Comment: @Josh What do you mean with "it double counts the sets"?

Comment: ABCDE which is two possibilities: ABCD and E is matched with a {3,} quantifier presumably because ABCD, B, CD, CDE, and E are all contained within it. However, if I run the regular expression globally without the quantifier it successfully identifies ABCD and E separately

Comment: @Josh I understand. Do you want the 3rd line of the example to be matched, even if the expressions are sparsed instead of concatenated? About the other lines, I guess: 1) no 2) yes 4) no

Comment: @horcrux, yes! Which I know complicates things....

Comment: @Josh If [this](https://regex101.com/r/dlVQ16/2/) is ok, I'd publish an answer ;-)

Comment: Are the options you listed the only valid ones? If so, you should probably rethink your regular expression as it could match unwanted combinations (ADD for example)

Comment: @horcrux, yes that works for this example, but unfortunately fits a little too specifically to this, my real list is 2k+ combinations from 1-8 characters. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @FélixCaron you're right, but I think I need to just accept those....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl or C++, almost different ends of the spectrum. You at least need
*atomic groups* to keep the longest substrings.

If the engine you're using doesn't have atomic groups then it won't do this.

`(?m)^(?>.*?(?:ABCD|AD|ACD|BDC|BD|B|CDE|CD|EDA|EDB|E)){3}`

Expanded

```
 (?m)          # Multi-line mode
 ^             # Beginning of line
 (?>           # Atomic group, get one of these exactly 3 times
      .*?   
      (?:
           ABCD
        |  AD
        |  ACD
        |  BDC
        |  BD
        |  B
        |  CDE
        |  CD
        |  EDA
        |  EDB
        |  E
      )
 ){3}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work either, this will match a string with `ABCDCD` which only contains two from the given set. I've never used atomic grouping, so thanks for the direction!

Comment: @Josh - I think this works now. It has to be checked from the beginning of the line, otherwise it escapes the atomic group in the previous regex.